# Azman - Connection string for SQL Store

Tags: sql-server, azman

I'm trying to create a SQL backing store for Azman using the MMC snap-in. The tool asks for a URL-style connection string for connecting to the back end:

[image: Azman tool]

I have a URL-style connection string that works just fine for SQLExpress on the local machine:

```
mssql://Driver={SQL Server};Server={NL-089\SQLEXPRESS};Trusted_Connection={Yes};/AzManDB/MyTestStore
```

I'm currently trying the following for a full SQL Server backing store:

```
mssql://Driver={SQL Server};Server={dev-rtd-sql02};User Id=myUser;Password=myPassword;/AzManDB/MyTestStore
```

But the error I get back is simply "The parameter is incorrect". Sigh. Does anyone know how to correctly form this string?

Comment: Maybe try putting {myUser} and {myPassword} in {} like the server and driver are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this blog post
http://boyd.aspectdatasystems.com/2010/05/authorization-manager-azman-connections.html

the issue is the User Id & Password vs. UID and PWD.